# Get Viewport Width With JQuery and Use In Processing JS

Tags: jquery, processing.js

I'm writing a processingjs script that I want to resize depending on the users viewport width. As far as I know there's no functionality for this in processing, so I've been looking at JQuery and using `$(window).width();`.

Only I don't know how to get that value into the size(width, height) function in processing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Links if you need them:
http://processingjs.org/
http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call $(window).width(); in the size function.  Mixing js and p5 code is fine in processing.js.

```
void setup() {
    size( $(window).width(),
        $(window).height() );
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to update the size if the browser resizes... I've created a function to set the size and can pass it parameters on window resize event. However the drawing never gets redrawn...

Comment: setup() gets called once at the beginning of a processing program. 
draw() gets called continuously.