# how can processing.js detect browser's size?

Tags: javascript, browser, responsive-design, processing.js

As mentioned, how can processing.js respond to a browser's size? (responsive design)
i've tried screen.width and screen.height but it didn't work well. It seems only detect the size of the computer's screen size.

**What's more, i want to keep pace with the window's size when dragged and changed the size of the browser**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 size(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

according to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/processingjs/2-U_P7_BHlY

or

```
void setup() {
size( $(window).width(),
    $(window).height() );
...
}
```

according to [Get Viewport Width With JQuery and Use In Processing JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631933/get-viewport-width-with-jquery-and-use-in-processing-js)

Comment: what if i drag and change the size of the browser? Is there any method i can keep pace with the size?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I approached this issue using Zerb Foundation 3 responsive web framework, Javascript, jQuery and Processing.js. You can take a look at [Living Map Project](http://www.livingmapproject.com/) if you want to dig through the source.

in javascript / jquery:

```
// handle page resizing
$(window).resize(function() {
var pjs = Processing.getInstanceById('livingmap');
pjs.resizeSketch(document.getElementById('div_p5canvas').offsetWidth,  document.getElementById('div_p5canvas').offsetHeight);
} );
```

in your .pde processing js code (note: the calculation was what I felt worked well using zurb's foundation 3, the grid I defined and how that translated as pixels:

```
void resizeSketch(int w, int h) {
  if (w < 680) {
    size(w, floor(float(w)/680*610) - 30);
    } else size(680, 610 - 30);
}
```

in your html:

```
<div class="flex-video widescreen" id="div_p5canvas"
<canvas id="livingmap" data-processing-sources="livingmap_2.pde" style="height:auto; width:auto; focus { outline: 0; }" tabindex="1"></canvas>
</div>
```